# Covering mappings

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, path-connected

If $X$ is path conneceted, fundamental group of $X$ is finite and there is a covering map $p: X \to S^1$ then $X$ is simply conneceted (1 connected)

Any ideas how to prove this?

Comment: What have you tried? We can give you better advice once we know where you're coming from. What tools are you familiar with?

Comment: $X$ is path connected, therefore connected.

Comment: X is simply connected => 1.path connected (given) 2.fundamental group is trivial. Proof for 2:  we know that fundamental gropu of S1 is trivial and that covering map is a continuous one, so there is a homeomorphism  between SOME group in X, lets say in point Xo and fundamental group of S1. To satisfy that homeomorphism is by definition bijective function, fundamental (X,xo) must be trivial as well. Given that X is path connected, fundamental group does not depend on  the choice of point, and given that fundamental of X is finite =>fundamental group of X is trivial.this is what i am thinking:)

Comment: I am not sure about this, so if you could take a few minutes to check this i would be grateful :) @HallaSurvivor

Answer (score 1):

Let $p: X \rightarrow S^1$ be a covering map. Then the fundamental group of $X$ is a subgroup of the fundamental group of $S^1$, which is $\mathbb Z$ (not trivial as you stated in your comment). You also know that the fundamental group of $X$ is finite, so in fact it has to be the trivial subgroup. Then $X$ is simply-connected.

Comment: why is the fundamental group of X subgroup of fundamental group of S1? @fish

Comment: This is basically the main theorem of covering spaces. See e.g. Hatcher Theorem 1.38.